# Change a mathematical function within certain range

Tags: python, if-statement, range

I need to code a mathematical function that will use different value at specific x position. (It would represent light passing through different medium)

I tried to make a very simple code first to see if it would work, and unfortunately I can't seem to properly input it as I get no graph.

```
def function(x):
    if x < 10:
       a = 1
    if (10.0 <= x <= 20.0):
       a = 0.5
    if x > 20:
       a = -1
    return x*a

x = np.arange (0,30,90)
y = function(x)
plt.plot(x,y,'b')
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `if x<10: a=1 elif x<= 20: a=0.5 else: a=-1`. Are you using numpy?

Comment: Well, it computes but I get the same weird blanck plot.
With x and y ranging from -0.06 to 0.06
I wonder if the problem doesn't come from the arange or the way I just plot the whole thing

Comment: The parameters of `arange` should be start, **stop** and **step**. You are passing 0 30 90...

Comment: Ah thanks, I started with linspace but kept having "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: I modified the step but now I get the same old error.
"if x < 10:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Your function is expecting a single value, try `y = list(map(function, x))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Bob__ wrote, you should use the `map` function.

```
import numpy as np

def function(x):
    if x < 10:
       a = 1
    if (10.0 <= x <= 20.0):
       a = 0.5
    if x > 20:
       a = -1
    return x*a

x = np.arange (0,30,1)
y = map(function,x)
print(*y)
```

Running this prints the following values:

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 5.0 5.5 6.0 6.5 7.0 7.5 8.0 8.5 9.0 9.5 10.0 -21 -22 -23 -24 -25 -26 -27 -28 -29`

I changed the values in your arange function to cover each condition in your mapping function. The `map` function applies it's first parameter to each element of it's second, iterable parameter.

Comment: The map function does the red line which is not what I want. However I didn7t know that function, might be handy one day. Ty for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
x = np.arange (0,30,90)
```

Is quite certainly wrong. Whether OP is trying to create a list with 30 numbers between 0 and 90 or a list of 90 numbers from 0 to 30, the function [numpy.arange()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) requires its parameters in the following order: **start** of the interval, **end** of interval and **step** (spacing between values).

Then, `x` is passed to `function`, which (given how it is written) expects to receive a single value as a parameter instead, not a list. In fact, the line `if x < 10:` generates the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

This can be fixed by either changing `function` or the way in which the list `y` is created.

One other thing that is unclear to me (given the explanation of the mathematical problem OP is facing) is if `function` is supposed to be non continuous (as it is) or if that is the result of a simplification of the actual code. I'll show both cases in the following snippet:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# OP function... almost
def func_1(x):
    if x < 10:
       a = 1
    elif x <= 20.0:
       a = 0.5
    else:
       a = -1
    return a * x

# Continuous function based on OP function slopes
def func_2(x):
    if x < 10:
       return x
    elif x <= 20.0:
       return 5 + 0.5 * x
    else:
       return 35 - x

# The correct order of the parameters is start, stop, step
x = np.arange (0,30,0.1)

# lists of calculated values created by list comprehensions
y_1 = [func_1(i) for i in x]
y_2 = [func_2(i) for i in x]

plt.plot(x, y_1, 'r')
plt.plot(x, y_2, 'b')

plt.show()
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And silly me for those stupid mistake with the arange...
Sorry for the unclarity of my explanation regarding the equation, it was indeed a continuous equation making the blue line what I was looking for. 

happy new year*